# Issue with reverse AVPlayer reverse playback

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am trying to add reverse playback to video which I am playing with `AVPlayer` :

```
let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")
videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url:videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
videoPlayer.play()
```

I searched and found if I change `AVPlayer`'s rate to `-1` the movie plays in reverse mode :

```
 func reverseVideo()  {

        videoPlayer.play()
        videoPlayer.rate = -1
    }
```

This does work fine but reverse playback contains lots of lag and it doesn't  play smoothly, is there any possible way to fix this issue. I have read other topic in here but did't help.

Comment: Do you see the lag only at start while trying to play in reverse?

Comment: @TarunTyagi yes

Comment: Did you try calling the `reverseVideo` method after 
`playbackLikelyToKeepUp` is triggered. You can set an observer to track this value. Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1390348-playbacklikelytokeepup).

Answer (score 3):

this code is worked for me to play video in avplayer in reverse from local filesystem.

```
let duration = (self.playeritem?.asset.duration)!
let durationSec = CMTimeGetSeconds((self.playeritem?.asset.duration)!)
self.avPlayer?.seek(to: duration, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
self.avPlayer?.rate = -1
```

Comment: This is same answer as Tarun Tyagi and it's now work, by the way `durationSec` is useless here

Answer (score 2):

Try Replacing 
`videoPlayer.play()
 videoPlayer.rate = -1` with
`videoPlayer.playImmediately(atRate: -1)`

Comment: Same effect ! still has lag and it's not smooth, can you answer this ? :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434586/achieve-smooth-video-scrubbing-with-avplayer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if following would work correctly since I have not tried playing an asset in reverse before. I think following is a good idea to try out to seek to end before starting to play.

```
player.seek(to: player.currentItem!.duration,
            toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
            toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero,
            completionHandler: { (finished) in
        player.play()
        player.rate = -1
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but still  has lag  !

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be helpful, but could you try assigning the `player.rate = -1` before saying `player.play()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var durTime: CMTime = queuePlayer.currentItem.asset.duration
durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(durTime)

if CMTIME_IS_VALID(durTime) {
    queuePlayer.seek(toTime: durTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
}
else {
    print("In valid time")
}
```

Now set Rate of AVPlayer to negative value

```
queuePlayer.rate = -1
```

Comment: How can I make it smoother?