# Achieve smooth video scrubbing with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am trying to achieve smooth video scrubbing with `AVPlayer` through `UISlider` I have searched and it seems Apple has a [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1820/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016828) and explained how to achieve this, but my problem is how should I use this method and change player current time with a UISlider:
`stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(newChaseTime:CMTime)`

Here is my code :

```
//Play Intro Movie
let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "intro", withExtension: "mp4")
player = AVPlayer(url:videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
//videoPlayer.play()


view.addSubview(slider)
slider.maximumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((player.currentItem?.asset.duration)!))
```

Here is Apple sample code :

```
func stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(newChaseTime:CMTime)
    {
        player.pause()

        if CMTimeCompare(newChaseTime, chaseTime) != 0
        {
            chaseTime = newChaseTime;

            if !isSeekInProgress
            {
                trySeekToChaseTime()
            }
        }
    }




    func trySeekToChaseTime()
    {
        if playerCurrentItemStatus == .unknown
        {
            // wait until item becomes ready (KVO player.currentItem.status)
        }
        else if playerCurrentItemStatus == .readyToPlay
        {
            actuallySeekToTime()
        }
    }


    func actuallySeekToTime()
    {
        isSeekInProgress = true
        let seekTimeInProgress = chaseTime
        player.seek(to: seekTimeInProgress, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero,
                          toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler:
            { (isFinished:Bool) -> Void in

                if CMTimeCompare(seekTimeInProgress, self.chaseTime) == 0
                {
                    self.isSeekInProgress = false
                }
                else
                {
                    self.trySeekToChaseTime()
                }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you link to a sample project demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm not using the same method as you do which is `stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime`, I thought I should help you with the seeking action of the player.

```
func sliderValueChanged() {
    var timeToSeek = player.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds
    timeToSeek = timeToSeek * Double(slider.value)
    player.seek(to: CMTimeMake(Int64(timeToSeek), 1))
}
```

Also you should set the `slider.maximumValue` to 1. Hope this helps.

**Note**: Please don't forget to handle `currentItem` optional value. If it is `nil` you should set the value 0 for `timeToSeek` variable.

Comment: Thanks but slider just change frame 0 to 1 nothing more.I mean from frame 0 suddenly jumps to last frame

Comment: Since I set my slider's max value to 1 the edit on code you provided would end the video. Currently I'm using the code I wrote on multiple projects and it's working just fine.

Answer (score 4):

On slider value change event, just call the

`stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(CMTime.init(seconds: (player.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds)!* slider.value, preferredTimescale: 1000))`

The Apples sample code will change the player current time. You can also adjust toleranceBefore and toleranceAfter if you scrub the slider really fast.

Comment: I changed the code to this : `stopPlayingAndSeekSmoothlyToTime(newChaseTime: CMTime.init(seconds: (player.currentItem?.asset.duration.seconds)! * Double(slider.value) , preferredTimescale: 1000))`  but it doesn't work at all ! when I change scroll nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

try to add selectors to your slider like this at the begining:

```
playerView.timeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerViewController.timeSliderBeganTracking(_:)), for:.touchDown) // moved
        playerView.timeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerViewController.timeSliderEndedTracking(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        playerView.timeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayerViewController.timeSliderEndedTracking(_:)), for: .touchUpOutside )
```

then in `timeSliderBeganTracking` set `isSeekInProgress` to `true` and pause your player and invalidate timers and remove observers if you have any

then in `timeSliderEndedTracking` 
seek to current time like this :

`let currentSeconds = Float64(self.playerView.timeSlider.value)`
`container.player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(currentSeconds, 100))`
then add the observers and timers back and at the end set `isSeekInProgress` to `false`

[HERE](http://binarymosaic.com/custom-video-player-for-ios-with-avfoundation/) you can find a complete sample of creating a custom videoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old problem, I encountered it too. The solution can help someone now. Apple sample make slider super smooth and pretty. To make the sample work:

```
private static var context = 1
func playVideo() {
  ...
  player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status), options: [.new, .initial], context: &VideoViewController.context)
  ...
 }

override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }
    guard context == &VideoViewController.context else { return }
    switch keyPath {
    case #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status):
        if let newStatus = change.map({ $0[.newKey] as? NSNumber }), 
           let parsedNewStatus = newStatus.map({ AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: $0.intValue) ?? .unknown})  {
            playerCurrentItemStatus = parsedNewStatus
        } else {
            playerCurrentItemStatus = .unknown
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

Observe and update playerCurrentItemStatus