# Swift video reverse seek to time

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, reverse

I have an AVPlayer which I'm trying to play to a certain second and then play it in reverse.

I'm using `player?.rate = -1` method, but when it's going on the reverse it seems to be very laggy,

how can I make it go reverse smoother?

Comment: You can try to use this link for smooth video playing [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434586/achieve-smooth-video-scrubbing-with-avplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434586/achieve-smooth-video-scrubbing-with-avplayer)

Comment: Thanks @Harry but still no go, the example you gave is not relevant to seek on rate = -1, it's still laggy ...